# I have a pair of magnets that when I let go they attracted and broke

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, collision, home-experiment

I let two magnets attract from a distance and when they hit they both broke a piece off of each-other. Why did the magnets damage each-other when they collided and is it possible to put the broken magnets back together? I have powdered the small piece and keep the powdered part in a bag

Comment: I have successful glued a magnet back together.

Comment: @M.Enns can you please reword what you said because I do not understand it

Comment: Are they ceramic magnets? It may be hard to repair them, depending on the direction of the break relative to the north-south axis of the magnet. Usually, when ceramic magnets break the 2 pieces repel if you try to put them back together.

Comment: yes they are but they don't since I have a mold an powdered the small fragments

Comment: The powdered fragments will not be usable in repairing your magnets because you won't be able to re-assemble them with their original orientation.  However, they might be useful in other experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most commercial magnet materials are quite brittle, and smacking the together will often cause them to fracture. you can indeed glue them together. Try some cyanoacrylate ("crazy glue").